# How to attach drawer slides to back of cabinet?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, drawers

[image]I’m going to be upgrading drawer slides in my kitchen cabinets. When I was measuring the current slides, I noticed the back of the slides and attached to the back of the cabinet with plastic brackets that stick into pre drilled holes in the thin back panel. How would I attach brackets to that? It doesn’t seem like screws would hold well in the thin panel.

These are face frame, thermofoil cabinets. Specifically on the island, where the back panel is double walled so to speak.

Comment: Photos would help... Depends on the slides; there are various solutions. Including but not limited to attaching a small block of wood to the back of the cabinet and attaching the bracket to that. If you get the slides from a woodworking store or old-fashioned hardware store, the staff is likely to be able to suggest something appropriate if you bring them the photos;.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just use slides with similar brackets?  Also, if the old brackets are screwed into the back, what makes you think new ones will have trouble?

Comment: They aren’t screwed to the back. It looks like a peg that fits into a hole, I think anyway. I’ll get some photos uploaded.

Comment: Photo added. Back panel is maybe 1/8 inch at best. Think screws would hold? The slides are screwed into the face frame, then pop into plastic brackets in the back.

Answer (score 2):

If you don’t want rear brackets/sockets, you can often do custom width side supports. (As you can probably guess, these can be fiddly to get right.)

Failing that (drawers in the middle of a wide cabinet, etc), you can create solid struts (1x2 would work) that the rear socket can attach solidly to. Horizontal is probably easier, though you could do upright, which would carry weight without relying on the strength of fasteners.

All that said, rear sockets into thin back panels as you’ve described seem janky, but for light loads, they seem to work.

Comment: +1 for struts resting on the cabinet floor.  I always do that when upgrading/replacing cabinet shelving or pullouts.  If I was manufacturing hundreds of cabinets I would not want to do it.  But if I'm repairing one, and especially if I'm using scrap wood for the struts, it seems like the "why would you do it any other way" way.

Comment: I thought about adding some 1x2 and building a frame of sorts.

Comment: In addition, I don’t mind using rear brackets, I’m just not sure that screws will hold in the 1/8 inch melamine, or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Don't be fiddly; use as big a piece of plywood that you can get in there, sitting on the shelf of the cabinet so it can't slip down, and screwed there (w/o popping through the other side of the island!), because I *am* sure that the screws will *not* hold in 1/8 inch melamine. Only problem then is your slides are 1/2" too long. **"side supports"** +1. OP had better look at what's available. I'd've said *you don't* because no one makes cabinets with drawer slides that way anymore. What are they going to upgrade to? IKEA is all sides afaik. Anything w/ back brackets isn't an upgrade.

Comment: I do think that full extension bearing slides with a rear bracket exist. (Or, more to the point, brackets exist that will work with bearing slides.) I like the idea of a full sheet back because it’ll look more tidy.

Comment: I will probably do that, it’s not a fixed shelf, so I will run the plywood all the way down to the bottom of the cabinet. Believe it or not, they do still make cabinets this way. This is a brand new house, haha. I bought some full extension slides and rear brackets to go with, so I’ll see how it goes. 

Thanks!

Comment: Another thing that may be an option, a 6 inch (or so) piece of plywood dropping down from the top. There is about a 3 inch strip of solid wood at the top of the cabinets that I could screw to. Think that would work?

Comment: A drop-down chunk of ply would totally work. Pockets screws at each end would be solid.

Comment: That’s probably what I’ll go with, sounds like the best plan that won’t immediately look janky when you open the cabinets. I wouldn’t think it has to be very thick, anything would be better than what is in there. I believe I have 23 inches of depth, I bought 22 inch slides. If I have to get shorter ones I will, no biggie. Thanks!